# Changing values of a combobox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

I have a question for Javascipt DOM manipulation. I have written an HTML page that contains two combo boxes. The first combo box contains a list of counties. The second combo box contains a list of cities within the county selected in the first combo box. And I can't figure out how to do the next thing: whenever the value in the fist combo box is changing, the second combo box will be update accordingly. I'd appreciate if somebody can help me, I am a beginner in JS. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the comboboxes as code in your question. By showing us your code we can make an estimate on the level you currently are and will clarify the parts you're trying to figure out. Any JavaScript which shows an attempt to make it work is also highly encouraged, as we will know what you've already tried. Include these things and your answer will more focussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions is as follows but we can show better solutions if you could provide with sample source code.

```js
var data = [
  { country: 'A',  cities: ['A - 1', 'A - 2', 'A - 3']},
  { country: 'B',  cities: ['B - 1', 'B - 2', 'B - 3']},
  { country: 'C',  cities: ['C - 1', 'C - 2', 'C - 3']}
]
// Need to modify logic based on the data format.
const getCities = function(selectedCountry) {
  const target = data.find(d => d.country === selectedCountry);
  return target ? target.cities : [];
}

const changeCities = function (cities) {
  let html = '<option value="-">Cities</option>'
  for (let i in cities) {
    html += '<option value="' + cities[i] + '">' + cities[i] + '</option>'
  }
  document.querySelector('#cities').innerHTML = html;
}

document.querySelector('#countries').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const cities = getCities(event.target.value);
  changeCities(cities);
});
```

```html
<select id="countries">
  <option value="-">Countries</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<select id="cities">
  <option value="-">Cities</option>
</select>
```